# HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 111, for class: TempA

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity A which has a relationship with TempA entity as per below:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID")
private TempA tempA;
```

Then in the doInHibernate I call this

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", code));
Object result = c.uniqueResult();
```

then i received the error.  TempA is a shared table so other service can actually insert in this table.  What I need is to prevent hibernate from calling this TempA.  I was able to prevent it from doing a left join with A, however, it still causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

At start - name of join column shouldn't be "ID". Id column is column for main object Id. this should be called tempA_id. Then if you want get this tempA objcet you should use

`criteria.createAlias(tempA, tempA)` to tell hibernate he have to use join, and then call something like

```
c.add(Restrictions.eq("tempA.id", code));
```

But shorter version is:
 `c.add(Restrictions.eq("tempA", tempA_instance));` you can operate on object and hibernate care of everything.